# regex to match $date0$ or ''$date0$''

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have a string which contains both form `$date0$` and `''$date0$''` (single `'`).
I am using this regex to match `(\$([^\$]+)\$)` but it's only matching `$date0$`.

What regex should I use that matches both?

Comment: [Your regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/Vs9hFj/1) both.

Comment: I want to include '' as well if it's present

Comment: You need something like: `(?:'')?(\$([^\$]+)\$)(?:'')?`

Comment: ('?\$([^\$]+)\$'?)  adding ' followed by ? will make it optionnal